# drop down list option

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Markup,

```
<span style="padding-left: 76px">
 <span style="padding-left:5px">
  <select id="select1" name="requestdbtype" value="<?php echo $type ?>">
   <?php
    $options = array('DB2' => 'DB2',
            'MySQL' => 'MySQL',
            'Oracle' => 'Oracle',
            'PostgreSQL' => 'PostgreSQL',
            'SQLite' => 'SQLite',
            'SQL Server' => 'SQL Server',
            'Sybase' => 'Sybase');
            foreach($options as $value => $type){
                          echo "<option value='$value'>".$row['requestdbtype']."</option>";
            }
      ?>
  </select>
 </span>
</span>
```

I'm having trouble displaying the options. The current option displayed should be the value of `$row['requestdbtype']`. But my display only shows the current value as all the options, please help.

Comment: rtfm. [this](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php) for example

Comment: Hi you have use `$row['requestdbtype']` as selectbox value so it show current value for all options. use `$type` in place of `$row['requestdbtype']`. and put a `if condition for check $value is equal to $row['requestdbtype'] and for that option put 'selected' = 'selected'. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$row['requestdbtype']` for comparison, not in your HTML. Note also the syntax of the `select` tag:

```
<select id="select1" name="requestdbtype">
<?php
$options = array('DB2' => 'DB2',
    'MySQL' => 'MySQL',
    'Oracle' => 'Oracle',
    'PostgreSQL' => 'PostgreSQL',
    'SQLite' => 'SQLite',
    'SQL Server' => 'SQL Server',
    'Sybase' => 'Sybase');
foreach ( $options as $value => $type ) : ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php if ( $value == $row['requestdbtype'] ) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $type; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is that of course all of the drop-down options are going to display the same thing. If you pay attention, $row['requestdbtype'] is going to be the same every time.

**What I assume you are trying to do is, use everything in that array, but set the one that is equal to $row['requestdbtype'] to be currently selected.** That is as easy as:

```
foreach($options as $value => $type){
    $selected = ($type == $row['requestdbtype']) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option value='$value' $selected>$type</option>";
}
```

Just a heads up, the ***($blah == $blah2) ? "some blah" : "other blah"*** is called a ternary operator. What it does is checks ***($blah == $blah2)*** to see if it is true or false, and if true, returns ***"some blah"***, else it returns ***"other blah"***

Ternary operators are very useful for compact code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach( $options as $value => $type ) {
   echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $type . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($options as $value => $type){
    echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$type."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `selected='selected'` attribute.

```
foreach($options as $value => $type)
 {
  $select="";
  if($value==$row["requestdbtype"])
    $select="selected='selected'";
  echo "<option  $select value='$value'>$row[requestdbtype]</option>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code must be

```
 foreach($options as $value => $type){
      if($value == $row['requestdbtype']) 
          echo "<option value='$value'  selected = 'selected' >".$type."</option>";
      else
          echo "<option value='$value' >".$type."</option>";
  }
```

I dont know what is your `$row['requestdbtype']` value but please check if this is `$type` then in if condition put `$type` in place of `$value` for show current option showing selected. In your code you have put `$row['requestdbtype']` that was the main reason for displaying only current option in selectbox number of times.

I hope it will be helpful for you
thanks.